# Removing special characters using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have one problem in this code. I want to remove all special characters but the square brackets are not getting removed.

```
string regExp = "[\\\"]";
string tmp = Regex.Replace(str, regExp," ");
string[] strArray = tmp.Split(',');

obj.amcid = db.Execute("select MAX(amcid)+1 from sca_amcmaster");
foreach (string i in strArray)
{
  // int myInts = int.Parse(i);
  db.Execute(";EXEC insertitems1 @0,@1", i, obj.invoiceno);
}
```

Comment: why you tagged jquery,css,mvc?

Comment: Where are square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Square Brackets are **metacharacters** in Regular Expressions, which allow us to define list of things. So if you want to match then using Regex you need to change your expression to:

```
string regExp = "\[\\\"\]";
```

Therefore, you simply need to include the backslashes before the square brackets to match then too.

If none of them are required in the expression, you can group then using brackets, and the character ? (zero or more matches):

```
string regExp = "(\[)?(\\)?(\")?(\])?";
```